# hover animation one by one in html using css

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, hover

I have four divs, which I am trying to hover one after the other continuously, my code is like below:

```css
#rij1 .content-overlayz,
#rij1 .content-details {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: stepped-pulse;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  /* animation-direction: alternate; */
  animation-timing-function: steps(4, end);
}

@keyframes stepped-pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<a href="<?php echo base_url()?>homecontroller/types/<?=$subz->id?>">
      <div class="ProductBlock" id="rij<?=$i?>">
        <div class="contentme">
        <div class="content-overlayz"></div>
          <div class="img-fill">
            <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>admin/uploads/types/<?=$subz->pimage?>">
          </div>
          <div class="content-details" style="z-index:99">
          <h3><?=$subz->name?></h3>
      </div>
        </div>
      </div> </a>
```

i used the following css to make the first section animate:

```css
#rij1 .content-overlayz,
#rij1 .content-details {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: stepped-pulse;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  /* animation-direction: alternate; */
  animation-timing-function: steps(4, end);
}

@keyframes stepped-pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

how do i make rest of the elements animate like this one after the other , that is 1st section will animate then stop then next will animate and stop and next, please help, thanks in advance

Comment: I recommend you update that second snippet with the rendered HTML since this really has nothing to do with that php code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error:** You are adding style to id which is being generated dynamically to the code and you might not be able to add the styling to all later on

**Fix** Add the styling either to `ProductBlock` class or to a new class if you are using it elsewhere.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function playAnimation() {
    let currentIndex = 0;
    $(".ProductBlock").each(function(index) {
      let element = $(this);
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(".ProductBlock").removeClass("animateThis");
        element.addClass("animateThis");
        currentIndex++;
        if (currentIndex === $(".ProductBlock").length) {
          setTimeout(function() {
            currentIndex = 0;
            playAnimation();
          }, 2000);
        }

      }, index * 2000);
    });
  }
  playAnimation();
});
```

```css
.animateThis .content-overlayz,
.animateThis .content-details {
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-name: stepped-pulse;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: steps(4, end);
}

@keyframes stepped-pulse {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0.5;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="">
  <div class="ProductBlock" id="rij1">
    <div class="contentme">
      <div class="content-overlayz"></div>
      <div class="img-fill">
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="content-details" style="z-index:99">
        <h3>
          Name 1
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="">
  <div class="ProductBlock" id="rij2">
    <div class="contentme">
      <div class="content-overlayz"></div>
      <div class="img-fill">
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="content-details" style="z-index:99">
        <h3>
          Name 2
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="">
  <div class="ProductBlock" id="rij3">
    <div class="contentme">
      <div class="content-overlayz"></div>
      <div class="img-fill">
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="content-details" style="z-index:99">
        <h3>
          Name 3
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="">
  <div class="ProductBlock" id="rij4">
    <div class="contentme">
      <div class="content-overlayz"></div>
      <div class="img-fill">
        <img src="">
      </div>
      <div class="content-details" style="z-index:99">
        <h3>
          Name 4
        </h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: not exactly, i want one element only to animate at a time

Comment: Changed the code accordingly, added JavaScript. Check it now, but make sure to remove your `#rij1` style and add mine

Comment: its almost there, but after all elements are animated, its not continuing, its animating the last element

Comment: still same issue

Comment: its working, but only 1 2 3 is working, and its going back to 1 after 3, 4th one not working

Comment: Check it now. it may work. Just replace the JavaScript

Comment: still same, last one not animating

Comment: i have added the snippet of the code and corrected it to make the result visible.